# Do we need more than the periods?

Tags: lo.logic, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, reverse-math, soft-question

Reading [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54818/consistency-strength-needed-for-applied-mathematics), and the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) on reverse mathematics, I wonder whether one needs more than the subfield $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathbb{C}$ of periods for applied mathematics, or indeed weak forms of pure mathematics.

Edit: This was the sort of question one poses to friends over a coffee, and be quickly reminded that *again*, somehow, one forgot that periods only form a ring. With some time passed, I think I shall vote to close it and leave it as a warning to others: this is not a good MO question!

Comment: Just an idle question...

Comment: The Wikipedia article says that it's not known whether $e$ is a period or not. I daresay $e$ is useful for applied mathematics... 

Comment: There once was a field named $\mathbb{Q}$, whose completions had among them "you". Your extension is $\mathbb{C}$, which has periods you see, but is algebraically closed too! (I guess "you" are $\mathbb{R}$ in this off-the-cuff-perhaps-not-even-worthy-of-a-comment-but-somehow-it's-what-I'm-going-with-limerick response). 

Comment: Heh, alright, Qiaochu and Cam. Serves me right for being slack. The 'weak forms of pure mathematics' par of the question still stands, though. :)

Comment: I'm finding "applied mathematics" and "weak forms of pure mathematics" pretty vague or not terribly meaningful signifiers. 

Comment: Agreeing with Todd Trimble, and even more, to the extent they are meaningful it seems to me an odd partition for this type of question. 
Say, very vaguely, it seems much harder to me to do all kinds of Applied Analysis without complex and real numbers than various parts of Number Theory. 

Comment: What is a period?

Comment: Ah, got it:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my knowledge is sufficiently up to date, it is not known whether the periods form a field at all.  So I would say yes!  We need more than the periods.  Even applied mathematics benefits from the stuctural simplicity of certain objects.  And as Qiaochu pointed out, it is not known whether $e$ is a period.

In general I would say that having a field like $\mathbb C$ that is relatively easy to deal with is rather benificial compared to having your theory based on something that is technically difficult to handle such as the periods.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I can't believe I forgot that periods only form a ring, again. Please vote to close this question.