# How slowly can the critical points of the Fibonacci terms grow?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, universal-algebra

Define the Fibonacci terms $t_{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$ by letting $t_{1}(x,y)=y,t_{2}(x,y)=x$, and $t_{n+2}(x,y)=t_{n+1}(x,y)*t_{n}(x,y)$ for all $n$. The Fibonacci terms are used in order to approximate the composition operation on an algebra of elementary embeddings with application.

Let $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$ denote the set of all elementary embeddings
$j:V_{\lambda}\rightarrow V_{\lambda}$, and let $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}^{+}$ denote the set of all non-identity elementary embeddings from $V_{\lambda}$ to $V_{\lambda}$. Recall that $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$ is endowed with a self-distributive operation $*$ called application defined by $j*k=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}j(k|_{V_{\alpha}})$. Let $\equiv^{\gamma}$ denote the congruence on $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}$ where $j\equiv^{\gamma}k$ precisely when
$j(x)\cap V_{\gamma}=k(x)\cap V_{\gamma}$ for all $x\in V_{\gamma}$.

Suppose that $j,k\in\mathcal{E}^{+}_{\lambda}$ and $\mathrm{crit}(k)\geq\mathrm{crit}(j)$. Then what are some lower bounds of the [necessarily finite](https://mathoverflow.net/a/218395/22277) cardinality
$$|\langle j,k\rangle\equiv^{\mathrm{crit}(t_{2n+1}(j,k))}|?$$
What are some lower bounds of the [necessarily finite](https://mathoverflow.net/a/218395/22277) cardinality 
$$|\{\mathrm{crit}(l)|l\in\langle j,k\rangle,\mathrm{crit}(l)\leq\mathrm{crit}(t_{2n+1}(j,k))\}|?$$

Comment: Aha so $y,x,yx,xyx,yxxyx,\cdots$

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz If I understand the setup correctly, the $*$ operation is not associative, hence the positions of brackets in the terms are significant.

Comment: All right, I've seen just about enough. Closers: this question seems reasonable and I am practically certain to reopen it if it gets closed. A judgment to close should be supported by some knowledge of the area. Joseph: quit fanning the flames by calling people trolls. @GerryMyerson: while Joseph could have calmly answered your question, he is right that this is standard notation. In ZFC, the recursive definition of $V_\alpha$ for ordinals $\alpha$ (Jech, p. 64) is that $V_0 = \emptyset, V_{\alpha+1} = P(V_\alpha)$, and $V_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} V_\beta$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: @Todd Joseph *did* answer both Aaron and Gerry. For instance, Aaron's second comment was in response to Joseph's reply, and Joseph replied to it as well. (And, after a few days, he deleted his comments.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, you're right. But it's hard to tell whether those who asked ever saw his replies, since deleted comments are invisible to all except site moderators and community managers.

Comment: Whenever I ask a question like this one, I always get a slew of downvotes from entities who know absolutely nothing about the subject matter. It is a continual pattern.

Comment: There is a reason that I have deleted my comments. I do not clarify anything about standard notation when several people go to this post just to throw downvotes and close votes at it.